# How to control JSeparator size?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create this interface:

[image]

As you can tell, the separators have a custom size that does not span the entirety of the parents width, unlike what I came up with:

[image]

If you google "JSeparator size" there are no relevant SO results. A sizing option seems to be missing from the docs (there is something but for `JToolBar`).

I would like to control the width and the height of the `JSeparator`. If that's not possible however, I'm open to other alternatives.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code which builds the UI.  The LayoutManager you are using will be relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

If you only care about visuals add padding to the container that encloses the elements. You can use `JPanel` with `EmptyBorder` however there might be a better approach if you are using something more powerful than `BoxLayout`:

```
JPanel p = new JPanel();
p.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 20, 0, 20)); // 20 px on left and right
p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
p.add(new JLabel("pic1"));
p.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
p.add(new JSeparator());
p.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
p.add(new JLabel("pic2"));
```